# Best way to tackle deadlocks

Tags: sql-server-2005, jdbc, spring-jdbc, database-deadlocks

Its simple question , but I wasted few days with having any clear solution over it.

I am using spring jdbc templates as my DAO layer mssql sever 2005 as my database and we have a order entry system. Now we are getting so many dead lock scenarios when we have more than 5 people on the system. it seems lock happens when people try to create new order while others updating existing orders. It seems a conflict between insert and update statement for same table.

I did few thing to fix this and didn't work any of them. So now I am thinking to introduce java.util.semaphore or a Lock and control the concurrent access of threads, or just I can go for Synchronized methods or blocks.

What do you guys think about this? Is there any better way of handling this on data base server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a semaphore equivalent solution on the database side using sp_getApplock. But most of the times, that is not necessary. Different types of deadlocks requires different kind of treatment. Have a look at the posts in the below link to see how to fix common deadlock patterns.
http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/06/sql-server-deadlocks-and-live-lockscommon-patterns/

If you can capture your specific deadlock with trace flag 1222 and post the trace details here, we will be able to help you further.